# TextView error issues

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener, android-button

My problem is: I cannot make the button change the text in the TextView and the TextView is not registering. The error is TextView can't be resolved.

```
   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
      textView.setText("@string/htmll1");
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrives the TextView, you should use the findViewById, just like you do on the button. And to retrieves a string on the string.xml, you should use:

```
getString(R.string.htmll1)
```

The code:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
   textView.setText(getString(R.string.htmll1));
}
```

Comment: still has the textView error at the begining of the last line but thank you for the string help

Comment: So, can you post the entire code (.java and the xml)? Then we can check what's going on...

Comment: @TylerLund, you need to add the new code using the same account with which you asked the question, otherwise it will be rejected by the moderators (I just saw your edit get rejected).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure  you have done this or not yet, but you need to creat an instance of that textView. Basically, give it a variable like you did for button.

add something like:

TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourtextviewname);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.htmll1));
```